# How to read a stream of data fetched on client side - JavaScript, Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, fetch

I have created a simple proxy using Node (Express), where I am reading a pdf file from a remote server. I am able to read the file in chunks, and sending the chunks in response as `res.write()`. When I log the data, I can see all the streaming, but I can't receive the chunks on the front end. I am calling the endpoints correctly, but I want to get a response for each chunk is read.

**Client Side code**

```js
    fetch('http://localhost:8003/pdf-cors')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

**Node Express code**

```js
app.get('/pdf-cors', (req, res) => {
    https.get('https://www.mazda.com/globalassets/en/assets/csr/download/2017/2017_all.pdf')
        .on('response', response => {
        response.on('data', data => {
            console.log("[Reading File]...");
            res.write(data);
        })
        response.on('end', _ => {
            console.log("File reading done !");
        })
    })
});
```

> Note: When I put `res.end()` right after `res.write(data)` I am able to see the first chunk passed to the client in the console, but then I get an error says `Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after the end`.

The only thing that I want is to see each chunk being passed to the front end.

Comment: why don't you call `res.end()` in `response.on('end'...)`?

Comment: because thats called at the very end

Comment: If you never close the write stream (with `res.end()`) - you won't get the output sent to the client. If reading the file has ended (at the end), the writing has ended _at that same point_.

Comment: You could (should maybe) use `pipe` like this: `req.pipe(request.get(target)).pipe(res);`

Comment: I get that, but that still won't solve my problem. Because I want to receive the file in chunks, isn't it possible to have it in chunks each time the write is called I update the client ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

Comment: Are you saying you want a separate response for every chunk of the file? If so, why? That would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: @EstusFlask can you make it an answer, this was really helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch API allows to stream data with [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream).

On client side a stream can be read like:

```
  let res = await fetch('...');
  let reader = res.body.getReader();
  let result;
  let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf8');
  while (!result?.done) {
    result = await reader.read();
    let chunk = decoder.decode(result.value);
    console.log(chunk);
  }
```

Comment: This helped me parse a variety of errors - thanks!!

Comment: how can we turn it into a blob url and use it on a video element ?
i mean , to assign it to video element , must either create a blob url , or create a mediaStream of it to assign to the video's srcObject . none are possible as i tried .

Answer (score 0):

If you only need server to client events you can use EventStream with server-sent events.

```
export const apiEventSourceStream = async (onMessage) => {
  const url = `${API_IRL}/query-stream`;
  const eventSource = new EventSource(url);

  eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
    onMessage(event.data);
  };

  eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error("EventSource error: ", error);
    eventSource.close();
  };

  return () => eventSource.close();
};
```